# Only can't access Facebook and Youtube

Tags: vpn

I use tor and  it opens up any website but Facebook and Youtube, although I can access them by a proxy. I'm in middle east, what should I do? 348205

Comment: What happens when you try to load any other website in Torbrowser? What happens when you try to load Facebook or Youtube?

Comment: Youtube is owned by Google.
Google tend to dislike Tor and either block Tor users or require Tor users to fill in a captcha.
I imagine Facebook is the same.

I can't really give you a satisfying solution, sorry. You may need to just use your other proxy instead

Comment: user194: I have never been blocked out of youtube (nor facebook) when using Tor. a Tor user: what message do you get from the browser when you try to open the sites?